# How can I insert a char at the beginning of a line rather than at the end?

Tags: c, io, ansi-c

I am a beginner to C, and essentially, I am trying to read a file char by char, and echo the characters to the output, but also, at the start of every line, include the line number. I have managed to figure out how to count the lines, but when I attempt to insert the line number, I can't figure out how to get it to insert on the next line, rather than immediately upon encountering the newline.

Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    int c, nl;

    nl = 1; 
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("testWords.in", "r");

    if (file) {
        printf("%d. ", nl);
        while((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                ++nl;
                printf("%d", nl);
            }
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
1. The Three Laws of Robotics:2
First: A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction,3
   allow a human being to come to harm;4
Second: A robot must obey the orders given it by human beings5
   except where such orders would conflict with the First Law;6
Third: A robot must protect its own existence as long as7
such protection does not conflict with the First or Second Law;8
The Zeroth Law: A robot may not harm humanity, or, by inaction,9
    allow humanity to come to harm.10
    -- Isaac Asimov, I, Robot11
```

Comment: Tip: Print the linefeed *before* the number. You're so close! It's an order-of-operations thing.

Comment: @tadman Aw man, can't believe it was that simple. Thanks very much! Any idea how I can prevent the final line number 11. from printing?

Comment: Suggest `putchar(c);` instead of `printf ("%c", c);` (there is no conversion required `:)` The compiler will optimize this for you, but being explicit shows an understanding of the basic tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to print the new line character, `\n`, before you print the line number. You can fix this simply by moving your print char line above the if statement.

```
int main(void) {
    int c, nl;

    nl = 1; 
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("testWords.in", "r");

    if (file) {
        printf("%d. ", nl);
        while((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            printf("%c", c);
            if (c == '\n') {
                ++nl;
                printf("%d", nl);
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without changing what you have too much, you can prevent printing the extra line number by logging the previous char. Wait to print the line number until the last char was `\n` and you are on a new line. This way the `EOF` will trigger before an extraneous line number is printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, nl, p;

    nl = 1;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("testWords.in", "r");

    if (file) {
        printf("%d. ", nl);
        while((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (p == '\n') {
                ++nl;
                printf("%d", nl);
            }
            p = c;
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally fixed it, can't believe I didn't see that sooner. Any suggestions as to how I can prevent that final line number from printing? It reads the final new line character, and then prints an 11 at the bottom, followed by a blank line, when I want it to stop at 10.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get it to insert on the next line, rather than immediately upon encountering the newline.

Simple keep track of when the character  read is the first in the line.

This well handles a file with no lines and a file where the last line does not end with a `'\n'`.

```
    int nl = 0; 
    int start_of_line = 1;
    while((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
      if (start_of_line) {
        printf("%d ", nl++);
      }
      printf("%c", c);
      start_of_line = (c == '\n');
    }
```

Comment: That's an UV for the clever use of the conditional as a toggle on `start_of_line`....